# Turn off anti-alias for font in Emacs 23

Tags: emacs, fonts

How to I disable anti-aliasing for fonts in the Windows version of Emacs 23?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question - Google was no help.
Id like to know how to do this under X11? (The answer below is Windows only.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the `antialias=none` option for your fonts, as stated in [GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Fonts.html)

Comment: More explicitly, you hit `M-x customize` and then choose `Faces` and again `Basic Faces`. There you will find the default face where you can turn off the anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 7):

As I couldn't find a satisfactory answer to this one for a long time, I thought it wouldn't hurt to add this link to this discussion, as the above does not generally work on Linux:

http://keyboardconnoisseur.blogspot.com/2011/04/turning-off-antialiasing-for-specific.html

The problem is that under Linux, emacs doesn't seem to be doing a lot of font handling at all, and you need to disable the antialiasing elsewhere.

Comment: -1 because it doesn't answer the question as asked here (please open a new question that you answer yourself), and the link is useless since it's not a permalink to a specific item.

Answer (score 5):

If others were searching for how to disable anti-aliasing in OS X, you can run

```
defaults write org.gnu.Emacs AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 999
```

Comment: Works for me as of 2018 in Mojave

Comment: This worked for me for default font, but bold fonts were still antialiased until added this to .emacs: ```(setq-default mac-allow-anti-aliasing nil)```

Answer (score 0):

Never have run Mac OS X, so usable only for Linux + Windows:

```
(defvar my-preferred-font
  (cond
   ((eq window-system 'x)
    "-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--14-*-*-*-c-*-iso10646-1")
   ((eq window-system 'w32)
    "Courier New-10:antialias=none")
   (t nil)))
(when my-preferred-font
  (set-frame-font my-preferred-font)
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'latin my-preferred-font)
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'phonetic my-preferred-font)
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'cyrillic my-preferred-font)
  (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'greek my-preferred-font))
```

Whose uses only ASCII it is enough to follow official suggestion:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Courier New-10:antialias=none"))
```

I work with cyrillic, greek and IPA texts so need to define defaults for fontsets...